# Dart upload file to asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, dart, file-upload

I have a dart function that looks like this:

```
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> httpFilePost(Uri uri,
      {String fileName, String key, Uint8List fileBytes}) async {
    var delay = new Duration(milliseconds: 200);
    var tokenRetried = false;
    while (true) {
      final token = await getRefreshToken();

      final request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
      request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(key, fileBytes));
      if (token != null && token.isNotEmpty)
        request.headers['authorization'] = 'bearer $token';

      final response = await retry(() => request.send(),
          retryIf: (e) => e is SocketException || e is TimeoutException);

      if (response.statusCode == 503 || response.statusCode == 502) {
        await Future.delayed(delay);
        delay = new Duration(milliseconds: delay.inMilliseconds * 2);
      } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        if (!tokenRetried && refreshToken != null && await refreshToken()) {
          tokenRetried = true;
          continue;
        }

        throw HttpSecurityException(
            "The user is not authorized to access the endpoint",
            uri: uri);
      } else {
        return response;
      }
    }
  }
```

Basically it appends the refresh header, and then uploads the file. key is the name of the parameter in the web api method that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost("UploadVideo"), DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadVideo([FromQuery] string contentId, IFormFile file, [FromServices] IOptions<ConnectionStrings> connectionStrings, [FromQuery] Languages language = Languages.English, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
```

I figured, easy peasy this will work and I'll be done.

Except asp.net core throws that the file field is required.

I checked the raw request and it appears to be correct and clearly tags the file field.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What problem are you meeting? Do you mean asp.net core web API will throw the validation error? If that is the case, which fields will throw this error, please check the value.

Comment: Per my question, "file field is required" is the validation error that comes back from asp.net core.  Despite the file having the key set to "file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the filename in:

`request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(key, fileBytes));`

change to:

`request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(key, fileBytes, filename: filename));`